# Unable to start Logstash server and throwing error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I want to pass  log file as an input to a Logstash input. I have added /bin to the environment variable path so that I can access it from anywhere.

Below is my conf file:

**logstash.conf**

```
input{
 path => "D:\nest\es-logging-example\log\info\info.log"
 start_position => beginning
}
output{
 elasticsearch{
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "indexforlogstash"
 }
}
```

After running this using `logstash -f "D:\nest\es-logging-example\logstash.conf"` its showing below  error in terminal.

```
 `
[2022-03-15T16:14:49,851][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to 
execute action 
{:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, 
:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ 
\\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\" at line 2, column 11 (byte 19) after input{\r\n     
path ", :backtrace=>["C:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash- 
core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", 
"org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:189:in `initialize'", 
"org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'", 
"C:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in 
`initialize'", "C:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash- 
core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:50:in `execute'", 
"C:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:376:in `block in 
converge_state'"]}`
```

What is this error about?

Comment: please add error as string insted of screenshot. it will help everyone.

Comment: See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

There's no configuration found in `C:\logstash-8.1.0\logstash.conf`

Specify the absolute path where your `logstash.cong` file is located instead:

```
logstash -f "D:\\nest\\es-logging-example\\logstash.conf"
```

You also need to modify your config file as follows

```
path => "D:\\nest\\es-logging-example\\log\\info\\info.log"
```

Comment: I am trying your solution by running using `logstash -f "D:\nest\es-logging-example\logstash.conf"` but its showing this  error.

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: I've updated my answer please try again

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the \ is an escape character in the quoted string in your config file.

Can you change

```
 path => "D:\nest\es-logging-example\log\info\info.log"
```

to

```
 path => "D:\\nest\\es-logging-example\\log\\info\\info.log"
```

So the \ characters in the path are escaped.

Comment: You might also try using a / as the path separator.

Comment: I tried both ways `\\`and `/` but still same error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is wrong, you need to specify which input plugin you are using, which based on what you shared is the `file` input plugin.

Also, you need to use forward slashes.

Try the following:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/nest/es-logging-example/log/info/info.log"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding `file` block its showing this error `[WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-L8UKCFI] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:2404}`

Comment: When I am trying to access `localhost:9200` its showing error on page instead it should show response from elasticsearch.